# How can I open a Windows Explorer window from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-explorer

I own a local PHP point of Sale, using wampp as my web-server (Win7). What I'm looking for is to find a way to open the Flash Drive E as we normally do by visiting My Computer - > USB Flash E: ... but using JavaScript.

I have found this code, which works perfectly as needed... But this only works on IE, I'm using Google Chrome as my POS browser but what Chrome does... Opens up a blank window!

Here is the code:

```
<script>
function CallMe()
{
 window.open("file://PCNAME/E$");
}
</script>
<html>
<input  type="button" onClick="CallMe()" value="Open USB" />
</html>
```

Is there an alternative way to open USB Drive E? Maybe by using PHP?

Comment: You're only trying to open the window, right?  You aren't trying to interact with drive contents?  As @madhairsilence indicates, the latter is a *huge* security issue.  Er.  Indicated.  In a now-deleted comment.  Just take it from me instead.  Huge security risk, the latter.

Comment: @Charles Yes, Just to open window.

Comment: -1 This is unclear. Are you trying to open the *local drive*'s contents in the browser or some *other computer on the network*'s contents in the browser (Javascript)? Or are you trying to open the server's folder and show it (PHP)? Or are you trying to upload a user's hard drive contents to a server? Side note: "open Local Drive C ... by using PHP" is a little scary to me.

Comment: @Charles okay but It works on IE ! Ok forget Drive C:, What if i want to open Flash drive? as E: ??

Comment: No Guys, All Maybe its my fault to add Drive C...I'll edit code above, I want to check Drive E ( USB Flash ) to check if the files transferred or not...Thats all !

Comment: You can create an href tag and specify file:\\\\[machinetargename]\\c$, but please not this only works in IE. This will open a windows explorer window, not a browser window.  Furthermore, this only works on IE, not edge, chrome or firefox for security reasons.

Answer (score 9):

You could allow the user to navigate their filesystem from the browser using:

```
<input type="file" />​
```

You can't specify a default location nor can the browser open it automatically, however.

Comment: This opens a file picker, not a navigation tool.  They are *not* the same thing, and act *very* differently.

Comment: @Alihamra You can't. The user must make all the moves for security reasons.

Comment: Without being able to specify at least the default location this cannot be considered a valid solution.

Comment: Certainly a "not possible" is a valid solution, especially when it is enforced by browser vendor security implementations.

Answer (score 5):

```js
window.open("file:///" + yourLocalOrNetworkPath);
```

Comment: This doesn't work in remote websites. It works only in local html files.

Answer (score 0):

Open file explorer in JS with :

`showOpenFilePicker()`
function.

You can pass the arguments `"desktop"`, `"documents"`, `"downloads"`, `"music"`, `"pictures"`, or `"videos"`

Handle the select fiel with :

```js
showOpenFilePicker("documents").then((fileHandle) => {
    console.log(fileHandle);
  });
```

`FileSystemFileHandler is returned`

Full doc : [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showOpenFilePicker)

EDIT : WILL NOT WORK ON FIREFOX