# Is there any chance to open windows explorer by given input file path name in angular 6

Tags: angular, file-upload, angular6, angular-file-upload

- Hello,
- am using the angular 6 and type script
- am running app from chrome
- developed input type text and input type file(display:none) and upload button

**My HTML**

```
<input #inputVal type="text" (keyup.enter)="uploadEnter($event, inputVal.value)">
<input style="display:none" type="file" id="selectedFile" (change)="uploadFile($event)" accept=".zip" multiple />
<img width="20px;" src='/assets/img/upload.png' (click)="upload($event, inputVal.value)">
```

**My Component**

```
uploadEnter(event, value) {
  console.log('read input path value ', value);
  // validating the Local path and open specified folder location
  /* const win = loadURL(value);
  win.focus(); 
  window.location.assign(value); */ // these are not working
}
upload(event, value) {
  console.log('event called open windows location and select zip file');
}
```

- from above code upload click event working and am able to upload zip file,
- my goal is **open windows explorer with a particular folder from(given input text)**
- can please give solutions or suggestions on this, save my days

Comment: This is not connected to angular. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119642/how-can-i-open-a-windows-explorer-window-from-javascript

Comment: I don't think it is possible in javascript, due to security.