# Custom upload file explorer

Tags: javascript, user-interface, file-upload, client-side

How can I customize the file explorer window when I try to upload files?

Or maybe something that can get the files from the user side. I'm thinking of doing the same with the `Share It` app that can display all files from user side.

[image: explorer]

Answer (score 0):

You can provide specific folder for the file explorer window to open when you try to upload files. You can [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119642/how-can-i-open-a-windows-explorer-window-from-javascript) and try one. This has several security concerns and works fine for local. You will have no idea about the specified directory when on server and hence my suggestion would be to leave it up to the user to explore and choose one.

> Or maybe something that can get the files from the user side

You can try [drag and drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) approach to provide a convenient file upload user experience.

Other than these, you cannot perform any other customization like design changes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Deepak, I know this idea of mine is crazy, but can you help me how can we pass by the security ?

Comment: Or plugins we can use to change the file explorer design when trying to upload files.

Comment: Hi @stranger_cool, No you cannot modify the window of other users, as we do not know what OS they use, and the customization is strictly restricted to the persons having access to that PC(OS). Hope this helps.