# Open explorer input file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

In a web page I have this HTML code:

```js
    function inviaDocumentoAjax(formId) {
        inviaDocumentoAjaxByForm();
        document.getElementById("file_1053761667559715321").value = null;
    }

    function uploadFile(target){
        document.getElementById("file_1053761667559715321").value = target.files[0].name;
    }
```

```html
<table align="left" border="0" class="very compact table rounded">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="position:relative;">
                    <input type="text" id="file_1053761667559715321" style="position:absolute;" placeholder="Clicca qui per selezionare un file  ">
                        <input type="file" name="documento" title="" style="opacity:0; z-index:1;" onchange="uploadFile(this)" class="ui primary button">       
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>              
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Carica  " style="background-color:#1678c2;background:#1678c2;height:20px;width:56px;padding:0px" onclick="inviaDocumentoAjax();" class="ui primary button">      
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I try to open input file explorer using JavaScript without success.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: I don't see any attempt to open the file input with js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I open a Windows Explorer window from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119642/how-can-i-open-a-windows-explorer-window-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open it by firing this line of code wherever you want it to open

```
document.getElementById("file_1053761667559715321").click();
//this line of code will open the file explorer
```

Comment: .click() isnt  jquery man, its a javascript method  check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) it supported by all browsers and as u can see their i didnt post a jquery snippet its javascript

Comment: you can also reference w3school for more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp)

Comment: `w3schools` isn't a good source, but yes, `click` is a vanilla js thing

Comment: However, "you" is an English word, whereas "u" is not ;). Also, this question has been asked many, many times before.

Comment: ooh so sorry about my "u" and did answer solved the issue for you or helped out ?